# Target org triggers (after insert, after update) don't get fired when insert/update happens on source org using Salesforce2Salesforce

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I'm using Salesforce2Salesforce. When a new entry is inserted/updated inside of the source org, the target org's triggers (after insert and after update) are not getting fired. Is there any way around this?